# SQL WHERE multiple criteria

Tags: sql

[Question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMaZp.png)

Question: Write an SQL query to recommend pages to the user with user_id = 1 using the pages that your friends liked. It should not recommend pages you already selected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT page_id recommended_page
FROM Likes 
WHERE user_id IN(
SELECT user1_id 
FROM friendship
WHERE user2_id = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT user2_id
FROM friendship 
WHERE user1_id = 1) 
AND user_id != 1
```

Why is this not correct?

Instead, I have to look for a page that the user never likes to get rid of the 88 which was the page that the user likes and should be excluded. Why I can't just filter it with the user_id != 1

Here is the correct answer:

```
Correct answer: 
SELECT DISTINCT page_id recommended_page
FROM Likes 
WHERE user_id IN(
SELECT user1_id 
FROM friendship
WHERE user2_id = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT user2_id
FROM friendship 
WHERE user1_id = 1) 
AND page_id NOT IN
#Pages user1 didn't like before 
(SELECT page_id
FROM Likes
WHERE user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Wait... could you please format your code properly and also provide a database schema

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving a dummy name to the resultant table from the subquery. Like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT page_id recommended_page FROM Likes WHERE user_id IN( SELECT user1_id FROM friendship WHERE user2_id = 1 UNION ALL SELECT user2_id FROM friendship WHERE user1_id = 1) Customfriendship AND user_id != 1
```